# Type of this in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, types

Is there a way to make a method to always return the type of the same class that called it ?

Let me explain:

```
class Shape {
  var mName: String = null
  def named(name: String): Shape = {
    mName = name
    this
  }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
  override def named(name: String): Rectangle = {
    super.named(name)
    this
  }
}
```

This works, but is there a way to do this without having to override the `named` function in all of my subclasses? I'm looking for something like this (which does not work):

```
class Shape {
  var mName: String = null
  def named(name: String): classOf[this] = { // Does not work but would be great
    mName = name
    this
  }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
}
```

Any idea ? Or is it not possible ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `this.type` instead of `classOf[this]`.

```
class Shape {
  var mName: String = null
  def named(name: String): this.type = {
    mName = name
    this
  }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
}
```

Now to demonstrate that it works (in Scala 2.8)

```
scala> new Rectangle().named("foo")
res0: Rectangle = Rectangle@33f979cb

scala> res0.mName
res1: String = foo
```

---

`this.type` is a compile-type type name, while `classOf` is an operator that gets called at runtime to obtain a `java.lang.Class` object. You can't use `classOf[this]` ever, because the parameter needs to be a type name. Your two options when trying to obtain a `java.lang.Class` object are to call `classOf[TypeName]` or `this.getClass()`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the singleton type can't be used for instances that are not `this`.

Comment: @pderofurla: It would seem like it should be possible with path-dependent types, but I know very little about path-dependent types in Scala, and I'm not even sure whether they're still experimental.

Comment: I don't think it's related to path-dependent types at all. And no, path-dependent types are not experimental.